# Prove that if a sequence is eventually bounded then it is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Definitions:

1. eventually: A sequence $(a_n)$ satisfies a certain property eventually if there is a natural number $N$ such that the sequence  $(a_{N+n})$ satisfies that property.
2. bounded: if it is both bounded above and bounded below.
3. bounded above: if there exists $U$ such that, for all $n, a_n \leq U; U$ is an upper bounded for $(a_n)$
4. bounded below: if there exists $L$ such that, for all $n, a_n \geq L;L$ is a lower bound for $(a_n)$

So I know the fact that each finite set has a maximum and a minimum; is this what I want to use in my proof?

Comment: Yes, you want to use that. Think about now to find a finite set that will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Since after $N$ terms the sequence is bounded consider the finite set $\{a_1,a_2, \dots , a_N\}$ and then the sequence $a_{N+i}$ which you know is bounded. Go from there

Comment: yes that makes sense. so I know that the set $\{a_1,a_2, \dots , a_N\}$ is bounded and I have the the sequence $(a_{N+n})$ is also bounded. Thus the whole sequence is bounded? Can I just state this? Have I given ample justification?

Comment: Let $M_1,N_1$ be the upper/lower bound of $\{a_1,a_2, \dots , a_n\}$ and $M_2,N_2$ be the upper lower bound of $(a_{N+n})$. What can you say now?

Comment: I can say that the upper bound of $a_n$ is the max of $M_1$ and $M_2$ and the lower bound is the min of $N_1$ and $N_2$

Comment: Exactly! So your sequence is bounded.